# Scikit-optimize for Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, hyperparameters

I am currently trying to optimize my actor-critic algorithm in MATLAB. 
What happens is that 3 neural networks called actor, critic and model are connected with each other and each contain their own set of hyperparameters. [Scikit-optimize](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/) especially the `gp_minimize` function seems to be a good sequential model-based optimization algorithm that I would like to use. Does anybody knows a similar optimization library for MATLAB or a way how to incorporate the Scikit-optimize functions in MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, only if you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bayesian-optimization-algorithm.html, https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bayesopt.html. BTW, your question is off-topic unfortunately as you are asking for an off-site resource.  Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  Also please take the [tour].